# MediaWiki (IIS) - CSS Is Not Loading Properly

Tags: php, css, azure, iis, mediawiki

I have a MediaWiki running in Azure Web Sites.  When I go directly to the site, the CSS for the pages load fine.  However, I have several redirects to the site in place.  When I go through the redirects, the CSS fails to load for any particular page.  Here are the specific errors/warnings in the developer console of each browser:

### In IE:

> SEC7113: CSS was ignored due to mime type mismatch

### In Firefox:

> The stylesheet https://login.foobar.com/some_guid/oauth2/authorize?response_type=id_token&redirect_uri=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.foowiki.com%2Fsome_guid%2Flogin&client_id=some_guid&scope=openid+profile+email&response_mode=form_post&state=%2Fload.php%3Fdebug%3Dfalse%26lang%3Den%26modules%3Dmediawiki.legacy.commonPrint%252Cshared%257Cmediawiki.skinning.interface%257Cmediawiki.ui.button%257Cskins.vector.styles%26only%3Dstyles%26skin%3Dvector%26*&nonce=some_guid_20150513234555 was not loaded because its MIME type, "text/html", is not "text/css".

### In Chrome:

> Refused to execute script from 'https://www.foowiki.com/load.php?debug=false&lang=en&modules=startup&only=scripts&skin=vector&*' because its MIME type ('text/html') is not executable, and strict MIME type checking is enabled.

I have been through links such as (along with a host of others):

http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Thread:Project:Support_desk/CSS_is_not_loading_properly

This seems to be a fairly common and recurring error (which I don't see much help for in regards to IIS).  Is there a simple rule or configuration I can apply to web.config to handle this?

Comment: The css loads if going through an embedded redirect (e.g. a hyperlink in the wiki) after logging in through the main url for the site.  However, if trying to type an alias link for the site in the browser to go the actual site, the css for the wiki will not load and the "css was ignored due to mime type mismatch" warning is displayed.

Answer (score 0):

Don't mask load.php behind that oauth2 authorisation, just let it be loaded.